# How to usability test a prototype of mobile app

Tags: usability, mobile, mockup, native-app

I've written "User Stories" in "Gherkin Syntax" for native mobile app and want to get it "User Tested" to find our any usability issues.

Do I need clickable mocks which can be shown to user on mobile ? What are the available tool ? How to convert user stories into mock-ups ?

Please let me know what's the best way to achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how much time / effort you want to invest. You could;

- create paper prototypes, different screens, and ask users to simulate clicks with finger, then change paper
- Create low fidelity prototype in Sketch / Figma, do same thing
- Create high fidelity clickable prototypes in Sketch / Figma, and serve them on real device for user testing

Answer (score 1):

Case like this I really suggest program called "Figma", its really simple and fast to create good looking mockups and you can also do the interaction with it. Figma provides also mirror tool for phones so you can actually test it with mobile phone easily.

edit* You can use Figma on browser or desktop app, you can also use it out totally free!